# Create mosaic from overlaping images in python

Tags: python, image-processing, mosaic

I have imageset which is provided from drone imaging system. Separate images do overlap for about 70%. Each image is tif file from which I can read GPS location (one location for each image). What I want to do with images is to merge them in the same tif file. In other words I would like to create mosaic from all the images available.

Furthermore, I actually have 5 imagesets. Each represents separate spectral band. So at the and I would like to create mosaic, which would consist of 5 bands.

Mosaicing for separate imageset is more illustratively shown on the picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/41gZm.png

I imagine workflow for marging like this:

1.) Create mosaic A_i from overlaping images from i-th imageset, where i=1..5 for each spectral band

2.) Create final mosaic B from all A_i mosaics where i=1..5 for each spectral band

I am wondering what would be the best approach to create such mosaic. I heard about dgal, rasterio, pygis etc. but I do not know which library is the most suitable, powerful and intuitive. At the end I would like to have everything implemented in python. Preferably within library, but command line calls within python will also do the job.

I hope I explaind my problem clearly enough. Any help and suggestions are welcome. Examples will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use PIL to concatenate images. An example is:

```
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open(image_file1)
im2 = Image.open(image_file2)

newIm = Image.new('RGB', (im1.width + im2.width, im1.height))
dst.paste(im1, (0, 0))
dst.paste(im2, (im1.width, 0))
```

if images overlap you will have to adjust the values where to paste them.
I hope this help with your issue.

Comment: Uh thanks for your answer, but am afraid that this wont help. My images are gray (one color) and I would need automatic alignment which would include GPS data.

Comment: can't you program the auto align by converting the GPS data to the size of the image? If you know the distance between two ends of the image, just factor it by the image width.

Comment: Hello, yes I thought about that but I dont know how to do that. I know just the size of an image and GPS location in the middle of a picture. But I dont know which distance does the image represents in reality. Do you have I solution how to calculate that. I assume that this is possibe, but just dont know how to do just that.

Comment: if the only information you have is the gps coordinate in the middle of the picture, the only possibility of automatize this process is if all the pictures have the same zoom. If you can count on that, than you have to manually adjust the overlapping of two images (try different values in the past position) and compare the values you used with the distance between the position of each picture based on their coordinates. You can use a distance calculator based on gps coordinates easily found in google.

Comment: Be aware that if the overlapping between two images is always the same this is not necessary, just find it manually and apply it for all images

Comment: Hello, yes the only information is one GPS location, but metadata also includes informations such as yaw, roll and pitch. All the pictures have the same zoom, because when the drone scans ground it flies on the same hight. What do you mean by manually adjust the overlapping of two images? Do you think this litteraly or by using some descriptor aligning algoritem that is based for example on sift? Do you think that the information about location can be used just loosely just to make rough estimation of translation? Just before executing the tuning of fine position?

Comment: use the past function from PIL in my answer and try different values for the x and y position. Begin with x = im1.width (no overlapping) and reduce it until two images are perfectly overlapped.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, will try that.